# JavaScript .click doesnt work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm, webresource

I have been trying to get this code working for multi select option sets for dynamic crm. My problem here is that this code works effortlessly in Chrome, does exactly what I want it to but in IE the .click event returns false no matter what, if the check boxes are checked or unchecked.

All this code does is take a option set and converts it to a multi select list and sets value into the two fields "l1s_trainingmodulesvalues" holds the value of the option selected and "l1s_trainingmodules" holds the label of the option selected.

Can some one have a look at what I have been doing wrong.

```html
<html><head>
<title></title>
<script src="../WebResources/new_jquery3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // function will be called when web resource is loaded on Form.
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList();
        });

        //Coverts option list to checkbox list.
function ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList() 
{
    var dropdownOptions = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodulesoptionset").getOptions();
    var selectedValue = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodulesvalues").getValue();

    $(dropdownOptions).each(function (i, e) 
    {
        var rText = $(this)[0].text;
        var rvalue = $(this)[0].value;
        var isChecked = false;
        if (rText != '') 
        {
            if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue.indexOf(rvalue) != -1)
                isChecked = true;

            var checkbox = "<label><input type=\"checkbox\"  name =\"r\">" + rText  + "<br></label>"
            $(checkbox)
                .attr("value", rvalue)
                .attr("checked", isChecked)
                .attr("id", "id" + rvalue)
                .on('click',function () 
                {
                    //To Set Picklist Select Values
                    var selectedOption = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodulesvalues").getValue();
                    alert($(this).is(':checked')); /*** This value always returns false in IE but in Chrome it works perfectly*/**
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                    {
                        if (selectedOption == null)
                            selectedOption = rvalue+"";
                        else
                            selectedOption = selectedOption + "," + rvalue
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var tempSelected = rvalue + ",";
                        if (selectedOption != null) 
                        {
                            if (selectedOption.indexOf(tempSelected) != -1)
                                selectedOption = selectedOption.replace(tempSelected, "");
                            else
                                selectedOption = selectedOption.replace(rvalue, "")
                        }
                    }
                    //alert(rvalue);
                    parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodulesvalues").setValue(selectedOption);

                    //To Set Picklist Select Text
                    var selectedYear = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodules").getValue();
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                    {
                        if (selectedYear == null)
                            selectedYear = rText+"";
                        else
                            selectedYear = selectedYear + "," + rText
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var tempSelectedtext = rText + ",";
                        if (selectedYear != null) 
                        {
                            if (selectedYear.indexOf(tempSelectedtext) != -1)
                                selectedYear = selectedYear.replace(tempSelectedtext, "");
                            else
                                selectedYear = selectedYear.replace(rText, "");
                        }
                    }
                    //alert(selectedYear);
                    parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("l1s_trainingmodules").setValue(selectedYear);

                })
                .appendTo(checkboxList);
        }
    });
}
</script>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head><body style="-ms-word-wrap: break-word;"><form><div id="checkboxList">
</div></form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkbox` variable does not refer to a checkbox element. It's a label (`var checkbox = "<label><input type=\"checkbox\"  name =\"r\">" + rText  + "<br></label>"`), which does not have a checked state.

Inside your `click` handler, change

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

to

```
if ($(this).find('input').is(':checked'))
```